# Getting blank page when viewing the content of an arrary

Tags: php

Please help me on this as I am a newbie on PHP. I am reading from a file and loading the content in an array. Now I want to display only one record but the result is giving a blank page. When I display the whole array it works fine but I put the if statement to get a specific record, it doesn't work. Please see below code.

```
<?php
    $strreturn = "H123458"; 
    $customerRec = array(); 
    $destination_url ="./users/patient.txt";
    $myfile = fopen($destination_url, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $c=0;
    while(!feof($myfile)) {             
        $customerRec[$c++] = fgets($myfile);        
    }
    fclose($myfile);

    for($i=0;$i<count($customerRec);$i=$i+6){
        if($customerRec[$i] == $strreturn){ 
            for($t=$i;$t<6+$i;$t++){
                echo "$customerRec[$t]"."<br/>";                
            }                           
        }           
    }   
?>
```

--patient.txt----

```
H123456
Hemede
1234567896541
2018-09-01
2018-09-30
CPT805
H123457
Mario
9876543214569
2018-09-02
2018-09-29
CPT280
H123458
Michael
3698521478965
2018-09-03
2018-09-28
PML209
H123521
Laurant
7532159852365
2018-09-04
2018-09-24
FRS965
H123954
Theos
9658741258632
2018-09-05
2018-09-19
OTH77
```

Comment: Assuming the array is populated correctly (which you claim it is), then your code looks fine - demo: https://eval.in/1056343 . I think it's outputting what you wanted it to (although you didn't say precisely what the correct output should be) but it certainly doesn't output nothing. A blank page could be indicative of your PHP script crashing - maybe switch on error reporting and/or check your logs to see what's happening. There's nothing in the code  above which indicates a problem.

Comment: The first part of this seems like an overly complicated version of `$customerRec = file('./users/patient.txt');`. See http://php.net/manual/function.file.php

Comment: Why are you adding +6 on `for($i=0;$i<count($customerRec);$i=$i+6){` instead of `$i++`? Just asking, cause for me it makes no sense in my head. Shouldn't you iterate through each entry without skipping 6 inbetween?

Comment: @D.Schaller because that loop is skipping from one ID line (i.e. the lines starting with an H) to the next, not looking for each individual line.

Comment: A blank PHP page is typically the result of undisplayed errors. See [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Comment: @ADyson Well... this seems more than legit. Sry for my braindead-moment :x

Comment: Your text has white space; use trim in your condition and it should work: `if(trim($customerRec[$i]) == $strreturn)`

Comment: You may also be interested in PHP's `array_chunk()` and `array_filter()` functions. If your record structure is consistently grouped into 6 lines, you could make this much simpler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very specific question but here goes with a solution that might give you some optimisation hints and it never hurts to explore the PHP manual

```php
// Load the file contents into an array, trimming away any whitespace
$customerRec = array_map('trim', file(__DIR__ . '/users/patient.txt'));

// Split the array into groups of 6
$groups = array_chunk($customRec, 6);

// Find the groups with the first record equal to "H123458"
$search = "H123458";
$found = array_filter($groups, function($group) use ($search) {
    return reset($group) === $search;
});

// Loop over the found groups and display them
foreach ($found as $group) {
    echo implode('<br/>', $group);
}
```

References:

- `__DIR__` ~ http://php.net/manual/language.constants.predefined.php
- `file()` ~ http://php.net/manual/function.file.php
- `trim()` ~ http://php.net/manual/function.trim.php
- `array_map()` ~ http://www.php.net/manual/function.array-map.php
- `array_chunk()` ~ http://www.php.net/manual/function.array-chunk.php
- `array_filter()` ~ http://www.php.net/manual/function.array-filter.php
- `reset()` ~ http://www.php.net/manual/function.reset.php
- `implode()` ~ http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php
- Anonymous functions ~ http://www.php.net/manual/functions.anonymous.php

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your line **if($customerRec[$i] == $strreturn){** with below line

```
if(trim($customerRec[$i]) == $strreturn){
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Your code is OK.
But the array elements probably have an extra new-line character at the end.

That is why the comparison in the if-statement does not work.
Try this line before the if-statement:

```
echo urlencode($customerRec[$i])."<br/>";
```

You will probably see something like this: H123458%0A

A solution for this would be to use a trim function around the fgets.